# Stub overriden toString() using Mockito / PowerMock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to stub a toString method of an abstract class that overrides it and make it final:

```
public abstract class ExampleClass
{
    private String someClassProperty;

    public final String toString()
    {
      return this.someClassProperty;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I stub it as it's normally done with the following code:

```
ExampleClass mock = mock(ExampleClass.class);
when(mock.toString()).thenReturn("myString");
```

At runtime when Powermock is doing the stubbing on the mock it throws a NPE:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate ExampleClass$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$.toString()
```

I have put the ExampleClass in the @PrepareForTest annotation. So does anyone knows what actually can be wrong with stubbing final methods and if I make mistake somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: I remember a comment in the API documentation like this: "So you are trying to mock/stub final methods? You naughty developer!". It won't work...

Comment: I forgot to mention that the class I'm trying to stub is from a third party lib. Just for test purposes I made a test class which is abstract with a final toString method and the stubbing worked fine for it. I don't see any difference between both classes and I'm not sure why on the external class it cannot evaluate the toString method. Does someone experienced such problems?

Comment: It is not clear (because you're missing the import statements) if you call the mock method on the Mockito or the PowerMockito class. Can you update your code?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I found what was the problem. The class also overrides the equals and hashCode method where one of the class properties is invoked. I'm not sure why PowerMock invokes the real methods while evaluating the toString but there was the NPE because methods on the property were invoked. Now everything is fine.